# How to know if a row was ever inserted in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to know if a row was **ever** inserted in a table?

I can do a `SELECT COUNT(*)` but that gives me the current number of rows, and it would return `0` even if a row was inserted and then deleted. This is the case that I want to detect.

I don't see anything relevant when querying `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'`

I am looking for a generic way which would work on any table even if there is no index, no auto-increment

I am thinking there might be a hidden internal index that MySQL keeps track of but I am not aware of it.

Also to make matter worse, the tables I have to work with are a mix of `MyISAM` and `InnoDB` ones

Comment: I think you would have to set this up yourself.  e.g. via creating a history table and using triggers: Edit: Actually https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-log.html binary logging might be an option.

Comment: @JeffUK I am afraid yes, just asking here to make sure I am not missing a simple way to do it. I actually need to do that as a way of optimizing cleaning a database in between integration tests, so really I would like to find a way to sort this out with a query. I don't want to be adding new tables just for testing purpose.

Comment: @JeffUK I'll have a look at the binary log, cheers! I didn't know about it. Not sure if it is gonna be quicker than actually truncating the table though :)